# How can I adjust the distance in a bipartite pie graph using igraph?

Tags: igraph, pie-chart, aspect-ratio, bipartite

I am using igraph (R) to draw a bipartite graph with pie shaped vertices.

Simple example:

```
library(igraph)
inc <- matrix(sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE, prob=c(2,1)), 10, 5)
values <- lapply(1:15, function(x) sample(1:10,3))
g <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(inc)
plot(g, vertex.shape="pie", vertex.pie=values,
 vertex.pie.color=list(heat.colors(5)),
 layout = layout_as_bipartite)
```

[tall graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZHag.png)

I would like to decrease the distance between the upper and lower nodes. If I use asp I get the following

```
plot(g, vertex.shape="pie", vertex.pie=values,
 vertex.pie.color=list(heat.colors(5)),
 layout = layout_as_bipartite, asp = 0.3)
```

[graph with adjusted aspect ratio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlb8N.png)

The nodes are not round anymore. This doesn't happen when the vertices are not pie.

How can I adjust the distance without skewing the pie shapes?

Many thanks!